# Implementing color palettes using SASS on HTML - PHP web app?

Tags: php, html, css, sass

I'm currently working as a front-end designer for a web financial application, and so far interface is working correctly, but now I have to make somehow possible for user to change interface main color pallete, and I would like to know if there is a possible way to send instructions from HTML or PHP to a .SCSS or .SASS file.

I'm currently using SASS on my local drive so the main color is $main: #0066FF; I compile it with PrePros and upload the CSS file to web hosting, but how could I make the value of $main variable on the SCSS file change when users desires? I found that Compass can make the recompiling process, but I'm still looking for a way to implement it on a CPanel hosting.

Another way I'm working around is using javascript to overwrite CSS classes but it is way too long and memory consuming. Any other suggestion?

Comment: writing Sass-Files via php wouldn't be the right approach. Also Sass-Files should be compiled on the server while publishing your app, as you do now. Best solution is to generate x different cssfiles you can switch via php or even javascript (via a body-class).

Comment: @Jeff I forgot the little fact that if the SASS its changed it will change on server not on client, but I realized too late before posting, hopefully I can manage to rewrite the main CSS file only the most necesary values change, but it will be a little harder to maintain. Hopefully minifying them would speed up caching too. Thanks for your answer Jeff, I guess a PHP switch would do nicely to store display settings on mySQL

Answer (score 0):

Since I realized too late that even if it could be done, changing the SASS or SCSS file would alter its properties not only for the client, but also for the server, on which case all users would see the same changes and that's not what I intended. As Jeff stated, creating different CSS files and switching them via PHP or Javascript its the best way. Even using javascript or jQuery could work, but for my case there are too much elements that should change their values. Hopefully if anyone has had the same question should better reconsider if altering SASS files is an option.